# Не применяется класс к кнопкам js

Tags: css

Пытаюсь применить стиль к кнопкам, а к ним он вроде как применяется в дев тулсе, а вот внешне сам стиль не меняется

(JS)

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.tabs_menu a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tabs_menu .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var tab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tab').not(tab).css({'display': 'none'});
    $(tab).fadeIn(400);
  });
});
```

(CSS)

```
    .tabs_menu .active {
    color: rgb(179, 137, 137);
    background: #FFF;
  }
```

(HTML)

```
<div class="switch-buttons">
    <div class="tabs_menu">
      <a id="bttn1" href="#tab1">О сообществе</a>
      <a id="bttn2" href="#tab2">Описание проекта</a>
      <a id="bttn3" class="active" href="#tab3">Ответы на вопросы</a>
      <a id="bttn4" href="#">Группа ВКонтакте</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: picture]

Comment: У вас там ошибка в консоли написана. Поэтому применяться она не может))

Comment: Это не про этот кусочек кода, а про другой

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
    .tabs_menu .active {
    color: black !important;
    background: #FFF !important
  }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в этой строке:

```
 <a id="bttn4" href="#">Группа ВКонтакте</a>
```

У ссылки стоит лишь `#`, поэтому при клике на неё вываливается ошибка, когда доходит до этой строки:

```
$(tab).fadeIn(400);
```

Т.к. *Jquery* это элемент, обозначающий идентификатор и он пытается дальше парсить, а дальше ничего нет. Если написать хотя бы вот так `#t`, то *Jquery* не сругнётся и будет работать

---

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.tabs_menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tabs_menu .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var tab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tab').not(tab).css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    $(tab).fadeIn(400);
  });
});
```

```css
.tabs_menu .active {
  color: rgb(179, 137, 137);
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="switch-buttons">
  <div class="tabs_menu">
    <a id="bttn1" href="#tab1">О сообществе</a>
    <a id="bttn2" href="#tab2">Описание проекта</a>
    <a id="bttn3" class="active" href="#tab3">Ответы на вопросы</a>
    <a id="bttn4" href="#t">Группа ВКонтакте</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не вышло(
Может моя ошибка в том что я как-то не так применяю стили к элементу

Comment: Нет, проблема только в неправильном селекторе из-за `#`. Пруф добавил в ответ

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, проблема не ушла. К тому же кнопка 4 будет отвечать за открытие ссылки поэтому там такой href временный. И кстати только к 4 этот стиль и применяется, только частично, только параметр Background меняется. На остальные кнопки не работает, сделал всё с точностью как вы написали